# 'gsutil cp' resulted in empty file when in python subprocess piped command

Tags: python, subprocess, google-cloud-storage

The issue here is that the file copied in the first subprocess below is empty in the gs bucket.

```
subprocess.call("/usr/bin/gsutil cat infile | grep '|N|' > filename | /usr/bin/gsutil cp filename
                gs://destination_bucket/destination_folder/filename", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

But if put them into two subprocess, it works with no issue. Is there a way to do it in one subprocess? Will one call is better than two call in performance? Thanks.

```
subprocess.call("/usr/bin/gsutil cat infile | grep '|N|' > filename"
                , shell=True, executable="/bin/bash") 
subprocess.call("/usr/bin/gsutil cp filename gs://destination_bucket/destination_folder/filename"
                , shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

Comment: 2 call are no more efficient than one call, so it doesn't matter, just do 2 calls and save yourself the headache

Comment: The first is clearly erroneous; you cannot _both_ redirect the output to a file, and pipe it to another process. Perhaps you need to read up on what a pipe means in the shell. The error is clearly unrelated to anything in Python; it would not work on the command line, either.